# Emmet: продолжение счётчика в ячейках таблицы следующей строки

Tags: html, emmet

Шаблон `table>tr*2>td{TD $}*2` [соответствует](https://jsfiddle.net/bw5errff/) следующей таблице:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TD 1</td>
    <td>TD 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TD 1</td>
    <td>TD 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Эта же таблица [генерируется](https://jsfiddle.net/fpxsu2q6/) и таким: `table>(tr>td{TD $}*2)*2`; шаблоном.

---

Можно ли сгенерировать такую таблицу:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TD 1</td>
    <td>TD 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TD 3</td>
    <td>TD 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

то есть, чтобы счётчик продолжился в ячейках второй строки?

Comment: Вы объявляете новый счётчик что в первом, что во втором случае. Использовать значения предыдущего нельзя. Если только не модифицировать оригинальный билд `Emmet`.